# VB project doesn't enter in debug mode after change to release and back to debug

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, .net-1.1

I have a project in VB VS2003 everything work fine until i change it to Release, compile and then back to Debug. Now i can run the project but it doesn't stop on any breakpoint, i had try on different machine and the result is the same, i have try with other project and everything work fine

```
 <STAThread()> _
        Public Shared Sub Main()
            Dim splashWin As New Splash 'Here is one breakpoint and it never stop
            splashWin.Show()
            Application.DoEvents()
```

Note: If I press the break all(pause) button on VS it launch this error: "Unable to break execution. Please wait until the debuggee has finished loading, and try again." But the application is running fine

Comment: Does it break on the `splashWin.Show()` line below?

Comment: no, it doesn't stop in that line or any other in the project

Comment: Have you tried Cleaning your project then recompiling it.

Comment: Clean, Build, Rebuild, delete the bin and obj folder, nothing work

Comment: Note: If I press the pause button on VS it launch this error: "Unable to break execution. Please wait until the debuggee has finished loading, and try again." But the application is running fine